# Can I write and read the pins of the GPIO just by using the shell?

Tags: gpio, linux

I do not have programming skills, but I have some knowledge using the command line of the shell. Is it possible to get access to the GPIO just from the shell ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Bash_shell_script.2C_using_sysfs.2C_part_of_the_raspbian_operating_system But then again if you can handle shell script you could also easily learn other languages, e.g. python.

Comment: @Ghanima Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Link-only answers are, well you know ;) Beside that I was sure that I read about that topic before on RPi.SE but did not find that reference for calling a dupe.

Comment: @joan, ok you made me do it. It's a stub for now but if it is not challenged as a dupe it could be expanded.

Answer (score 6):

[ELinux](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Bash_shell_script.2C_using_sysfs.2C_part_of_the_raspbian_operating_system) lists two options to directly access GPIO pins from the command line interface and other libraries exist:

1. `sysfs`, the virtual filesystem allows `root` to directly read from and write to GPIO pins by `echo` to or `cat` from various files in the `/sys/class/gpio/` folder.
2. `wiringPi` library provides a cli command `gpio` to be used by non-privileged users for direct access.
3. `pigs` utility, part of the `pigpio` library also offers comprehensive control of the GPIO pins from the command line (see [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) for download of source, installation procedures and excellent application examples).

Comment: The pigpio [pigs](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) utility allows comprehensive control of the gpios from the command line.